# bytes-like object is required not 'tuple' when trying to use query parameters

Tags: python, mariadb

In a phython script I read a value from a hardware module. This value I want to insert in a mariadb

I convert the hardware value to a string.

```
wert_float="{:.1f}".format(sensor1)
wert = str(wert_float)

mycursor =mydb.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO werte (feuchtigkeit) VALUES (?)", (wert)
mycursor.execute(sql)
mydb.commit()
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

I tried the statement with (%s) too, but at all tries I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./waterpi_sql.py", line 118, in <module>
    mycursor.execute(sql)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your query params to actual function params

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO werte (feuchtigkeit) VALUES (?)"
mycursor.execute(sql, (wert,))
```

Otherwise, you've assigned `sql` to a tuple, which is not executable, and the way you've written is not expressed in any docs that I've seen, so make sure you refer back to those

Comment: `mycursor.execute(*sql)` would also be an option, if `sql` were assigned the *correct* tuple originally (i.e., `sql = "...", (wert,)`).